# Singular or plural verb for compound subject?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-subjects

Which is correct?  "When quality and integrity matter..." or "When quality and integrity matters..."?

Comment: What do ***you*** think, and why? Questions asking for correctness decisions without context usually get closed without answer; we don't do your thinking for you.

Comment: Sometimes with these lesser-used, yet "heavy" nouns and objects, things feel a little weird. Try simplifying it a bit. **When John walks** to the store, he buys a cola. **When John and Jacob walk** to the store, John buys them both a cola.

Answer (score 1):

The number agreement of verbs in English is largely semantic, so you should ask: does the subject of "matter" refer to just one thing, or does it refer to several things?  In difficult cases, the answer will not be obvious, and the answer might not be determinate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two objects in this sentence, quality and integrity. They both matter. Thus, it's when quality and integrity matter.

Comment: That assumes that _quality_ and _integrity_ are independent count nouns that have nothing in common. If they are merely different aspects of the same phenomenon (which is what the OP appears to be wanting), then they're singular mass nouns and their concatenation is too.

Comment: Peanut butter and jelly is my favorite sandwich.