# "Designs and artistic valour (are/is) something that (run/runs) in his blood."

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses, subjects, compound-subjects

1. > Designs and artistic valour **are** something that **run** in his blood.
2. > Designs and artistic valour **is** something that **runs* in his blood.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: I feel like both sentences sound weird. I'd get rid of the "something that" and say "Designs and artistic valour run in his blood". For information about singular vs. plural agreement with compound subjects containing *and*, see [Singular or plural verb for compound subject?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246075/singular-or-plural-verb-for-compound-subject) and the linked questions.

Comment: First off, why do you say "designs" rather than the uncountable "design"?

Comment: is something / are things

Comment: "Designs and artistic valour are things that run in his blood."

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to hold on to "...*something that*..." then there can only be one subject in the sentence—not two. You could get around this by grouping *design* and *artistic valor* under a sort of umbrella subject, like this:

*A penchant for design and artistic valor is something that runs...*

Comment: I don't think the first sentence of this answer is correct. There is no requirement in English that a subject must have the same grammatical number as the predicative complement: consider the sentence "[the feelings of sadness are something that we will move through](https://books.google.com/books?id=S0dCCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA218&dq=%22are+something+that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2iujH9pfbAhUkyoMKHX4HBoMQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22are%20something%20that%22&f=false)"

Comment: I like the suggestion of adding `a penchant for`, but even that isn't optimal as the scope of `a penchant for` can be interpreted just `design`, as in `1: (a penchant for design) and (artistic valor)` as opposed to `2: a penchant for (design and artistic valor)`. If fact, I'd say `1` is the more natural interpretation for various reasons. Thus, I'd just do away with `something that` or replace it with `qualities that`.

Comment: @sumelic Although I understand that sentence, I don't like it. It sounds a bit "off". If I *had* to say "yes or no" to it, I would say "no."  (Although I'm not certain.) I would rephrase it to something like *we will move through these feelings of sadness* to avoid the very issue involving *something*. Or, perhaps better, *this feeling of sadness is something that we will move through*.